# How to reorder highlights in Preview according to page numbers?

Tags: pdf, preview, highlights

I read a book, while reading it, I highlighted some parts of the text. Now, in the side bar, when I choose the highlights and notes option, I see the highlights shown in random order, i.e the highlights are not in the same order as the pages. I would like all highlights in page x to come before page y, if x < y. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's been like that since El Capitan. Your best bet for now is testing out other PDF viewers.

The good news is that it supposedly is fixed in Big Sur: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/jjhrfz/is_the_issue_of_preview_showing_highlights_and/